# last item removing error in ViewPager on TabFragment android

Tags: android, webview, android-studio

i have two custom button Add and Remove, And when i click on Add tab Work good, after when i remove tab its go ok, but when i remove last tab then i get following error.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3699)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewAt(ViewGroup.java:3663)
        at app.burhanimumineenbrowser.HomeActivity$3.onClick(HomeActivity.java:184)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

When i remove first tab its del , second one also delete but after third tab i cant remove it, error say me null pointer.

Here is Add Button Code.

```
btNewtab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                COUNT_TAB+=1;
            // viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("New Tabs")
                    .setTabListener(HomeActivity.this));


            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Remove button Code.

```
 btCloseTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(COUNT_TAB>0) {
                if(TAB_CURRENT>=0 && PAGE_CURRENT>=0) {
                    System.out.println("CLOSE PAGE AND TAB : "+TAB_CURRENT+" AND "+PAGE_CURRENT);
                    COUNT_TAB -=1;
                   // int ichektab=TAB_CURRENT-1;
                    int ip=viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                    viewPager.removeViewAt(ip);
                    actionBar.removeTabAt(TAB_CURRENT);

                    //actionBar.removeTab(iTab);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

               //     viewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
                    /* if(ichektab>0){
                        //  viewPager.setCurrentItem(ichektab);

                               viewPager.setCurrentItem(ichektab);
                             //actionBar.removeTabAt(TAB_CURRENT);
                     }*/

             }
                }
        }
    });
```

My Adapter

```
public class TabsPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private long baseId = 0;
    public TabsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return new MyWebBrowser();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return COUNT_TAB;
    }
    }
}  please kindly suggest me about this error. Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve error. 
Th reason is viewpager pager  screen limit. By default there viewpager have Two page limit, but i write first time i used this code

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(COUNT_TAB);
```

And  i solved it

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(500);
```

and if use COUNT_TAB then add button code is

```
btNewtab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              //  COUNT_TAB+=1;
            // viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("New Tabs")
                    .setTabListener(HomeActivity.this));

            COUNT_TAB+=1;

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(COUNT_TAB);

        }
    });
```

Put pager limit after notifydatasetchanged.
Hope you guys understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in remove button:
before removing tab u making COUNT_TAB to reduce so it troughs NullPointerException

also in addtab button increment the count tab in last

```
btCloseTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(COUNT_TAB>0) {
                if(TAB_CURRENT>=0 && PAGE_CURRENT>=0) {
                    System.out.println("CLOSE PAGE AND TAB : "+TAB_CURRENT+" AND "+PAGE_CURRENT);

                   // int ichektab=TAB_CURRENT-1;
                    int ip=viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                    viewPager.removeViewAt(ip);
                    actionBar.removeTabAt(TAB_CURRENT);

                    //actionBar.removeTab(iTab);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 COUNT_TAB -=1;

               //     viewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
                    /* if(ichektab>0){
                        //  viewPager.setCurrentItem(ichektab);

                               viewPager.setCurrentItem(ichektab);
                             //actionBar.removeTabAt(TAB_CURRENT);
                     }*/

             }
                }
        }
    });
```

View Pager page change listener

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {
            NUM_TABS=i+1;
            btTabCount.setText(""+NUM_TABS);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {

            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
            PAGE_CURRENT=i;
            System.out.println("CURRENT PAGE DISCRIPTION : "+PAGE_CURRENT);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Tab listener methods

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    TAB_CURRENT=tab.getPosition();
    iTab=tab;

    System.out.println("CURRENT TAB DISCRIPTION : "+TAB_CURRENT);


}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
   // viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    //viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}
```

Comment: i update above question my viewpager action and tab listener implement methods. please rechack it. Thanks again

Comment: And also when i remove viewpager view and when i add new then it will open privous delete view at same position